# decimal.parse fails for currency string created with String.Format?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, decimal, currency

I have a field that I display via:

```
String.Format({0:c},amount)
```

This produces the string "$28.28"

However, when I try to convert back to a decimal amount, I get an incorrect format exception:

```
amount = Decimal.Parse(amount.Text, NumberStyles.Currency)
```

I also tried it with NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol with the same results.  I verified that the value in amount.Text is "$28.28".

Am I missing something?  Shouldn't these two operations use the same currency symbol and formats?

Comment: What is the resulting string from the `Format` operation?

Comment: I would also advise you use Decimal.TryParse instead of .Parse when the input is coming from the user (or anything external to your code).

Comment: Isn't that the point of the overload to Parse that takes the NumberStyles.Currency as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var amount = decimal.Parse("$28.28", NumberStyles.Currency);
```

works fine for me. Make sure your input string is what you think it is.

Comment: Very strange.  Restarted IIS, and now it works.  Something must have messed up the localization settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are these on different machines?
The machines be be setup differently.
The default formats are set in the control panel regional settings.